# Number of Water Tanks Needed- Interview Problem

Tags: python, list

Stuck on this question I got during an interview.
Suppose you have an array of houses "-H-H-H", each house needs to be close to a water tank on either its left or right side. How many water tanks do you need? Water Tanks can only go where there is a dash.

Ex. "-H-H-H" -> solution: 2 tanks needed, one option is '-HTHTH', or 'TH-HTH'

The solution I used is to place a water tank in between each pair of unserved houses that has exactly 1 dash between them, then after that, just assigned a water tank to the left or right of all the remaining unserved houses.

```
 s="H--H-H-H-H-H-H-H"
    L=list(s)
    N=len(L)
    House_count=L.count('H')
    for i in range(1,N-1):
        if(L[i-1]=='H' and L[i-1]!='F' and L[i]=='-' and L[i+1]=='H' and L[i+1]!='F'):
            L[i-1],L[i+1]='F','F'
            L[i]='T'
    print(L)
    for i in range(1,N-1):
        if(L[i]=='-' and L[i-1]=='H' and L[i-1]!='F'):
            L[i-1]='F'
            L[i]='T'
            
        elif(L[i]=='-' and L[i+1]=='H' and L[i+1]!='F'):
            L[i+1]='F'
            L[i]='T'
            
        elif(L[i]=='H' and L[i]!='F' and L[i-1]=='-'):
            L[i]='F'
            L[i-1]='T'
        
        elif(L[i]=='H' and L[i]!='F' and L[i+1]=='-'):
            L[i]='F'
            L[i+1]='T'
            
    Found_count=L.count('F')
    Tank_count=L.count('T')
    print(L)
    if(Tank_count==0 or Found_count!=House_count):
        print(-1) 
    else:
        print(Tank_count)
```

The code passed only 5/8 test cases I tried all the combinations from my side but still can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be appricieated.

Comment: And you're sure that the failing test cases are not the ones where you're supposed to check for illegal input, and input that has no solutions?

Comment: Yes I tried giving multiple S values like empty string no - etc, they return -1 as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I haven’t  test your code yet.
For my methodology
I will create a function to find best
Substitution for every tank that I place

Ex -H-H-H-H-H
The answer maybe like ;
-HTH-HTHTH (please validate you code)

But however
It may has multiple answers
Eg TH-HTH-HTH

Maybe this is the root cause

Answer (score 0):

Heres my Java solution

```
public class TankPlacement {
    static int findMinNumberOfTanks(String str){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str);

        for (int i = 1; i < str.length() - 1 ; i++) {
            if(sb.charAt(i) == '-' && sb.charAt(i-1) == 'H' && sb.charAt(i+1) == 'H'){
                sb.setCharAt(i,'T');
                sb.setCharAt(i-1,'D');
                sb.setCharAt(i+1,'D');
            }
        }
        for(int i = 0;i<str.length();i++){
            if(sb.charAt(i) == 'H'){
                if(i-1 >=0 && sb.charAt(i-1) != 'T' && sb.charAt(i-1) == '-'){
                    sb.setCharAt(i-1,'T');
                    sb.setCharAt(i,'D');

                }
                else if(i+1 <= sb.length() - 1 && sb.charAt(i+1) != 'T' && sb.charAt(i+1) == '-'){
                    sb.setCharAt(i+1,'T');
                    sb.setCharAt(i,'D');

                }
                else{
                    return -1;
                }
            }
        }
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < sb.length(); i++) {
            if(sb.charAt(i) == 'T'){
                count++;
            }
            if(sb.charAt(i) == 'H'){
                return -1;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int ans = findMinNumberOfTanks("H--H--H");
        System.out.println(ans);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you require the **minimum** amount of tanks and that you also have to detect if the input is an array with no solution, here is my idea that with an ok implementation should solve this in O(n) time:

-- (A) Let's handle the invalid inputs first:

In O(n) time we can check that:

1. input doesn't contain "HHH"
2. input doesn't start with "HH"
3. input doesn't end with "HH"

In all the cases above, return "-1" to indicate that no solution is possible.

-- Now that we know our input is valid, let's find patterns of "H" and "-" that can produce less than 1 tank per house (which is the obvious, but not minimum solution). By checking all possible pairs and all possible triplets it easy to see that the pattern "H-H" is the one that can reduce the amount of tanks required by houses, since we can just install a single tank between the 2 houses (write out all possible pairs, triples or quadruples etc and check that with no other pattern can improve the count, unless it contains "H-H" and as such can be described as "H-H" and something else).

-- (B) Our next step, also in O(n), is to count the occurrence of the "H-H" in our input. For each "H-H" we find, we can increase the tank count by 1 and ignore the pattern in further steps.

-- (C) Our final step is to match the remaining "H" with a "-" that should be on one of "H"'s sides and count tanks accordingly. It shouldn't matter the direction, but it is a good idea to follow the direction of the previous step.

These steps should produce the minimum amount of tanks required.

However, if you want to be extra cautious, you can run the (B) and (C) steps from the opposite direction and keep the minimum result as your answer. This is in case the "H-H" pattern, for some reason, occurs more times depending on the traversal direction (it shouldn't). You can do this extra check also in O(n) keeping the total cost of the solution still to O(n).

O(n) complexity with no smart implementation: keeping each step (A,B,C + extras) to their own for-loops. At worst you get: O(5n) = O(n).